# How to set root view controller

Tags: ios, xcode

I set up an empty app with only an app delegate class, then subclassed a view controller class to create a xib to layout the app and make connections.

But when I tried to run the app on iOS Simulator, I got an error which read: CoinToss[6212:f803] Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.
Program ended with exit code: 0

What do I need to do in order to create a root view controller for the app?

Thank you.

Comment: The whole terminated in response to springboard is the home button being pressed.  Applications are expected to have a root view controller, but expected and must are two different words.  I know that in the apple glpaint sample, that error comes up, but mostly because all of the view mucking around is done in the delegate.

Answer (score 25):

in AppDelegate.m

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];



    UIViewController *viewController = // determine the initial view controller here and instantiate it with [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;//making a view to root view
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're apparently using .xib files, load your view controller and the set the window's `rootViewController` property to your view controller in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 2 things for that..

1. in **AppDelegate.m** file: `_applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions_`

   self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
2. in **application.m**

   retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");

Answer (score 0):

Applications are expected to have a root view controller

Replace in AppDelegate

```
 [window addSubview:[someController view]];
```

to

```
 [self.window setRootViewController:someController];
```