# PushViewController from another UIViewController - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pushviewcontroller

I have a class like this,

```
import UIkit

class One {

    let btn = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 30, 30)
        btn.setTitle("Go", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: "goToClassTwo", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
    }

    func goToClassTwo(){
        if(AppGlobals().getIsFromDiffView()){
             let difView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: DiffView())
             difView.pushViewController(Two(), animated: true)
        }else{
             self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Two(), animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

A setter/getter class like this,

```
class AppGlobals: NSObject {

     var isFromDiffView = false

     func setIsFromDiffView(val: Bool){
         isFromDiffView = val
     }

     func getIsFromDiffView() -> Bool {
         return isFromDiffView
     }

}
```

And I have another class like this,

```
class DiffView {

    let btn = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 30, 30)
        btn.setTitle("Push", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
    }

    func btnAction(){
        AppGlobals().setIsFromDiffView(true)
        One().goToClassTwo()
    }
}
```

I am facing a problem here. When the 'Go' button in the class 'One' is tapped, then the 'Two' view controller is shown. But when I tap on the 'Push' button in the class 'DiffView' is tapped, the 'Two' view controller is not being shown.

I have checked setting breakpoints. The control does come to the `goToClassTwo` function in the class 'One' and the `if` path is being executed. But the 'Two' view controller is not shown. `difView.pushViewController` is called. But it is not pushing to the next view.

**NOTE:** I am not using storyboard

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check if the second time, AppGlobals().getIsFromDiffView() is false.

Comment: It is true only. The control gets into the `if` path. But nothing happens.

Comment: the problem is, you create a UINavigationController and push two() to it. But you never present the created navigation controller to your app window. So the view is definitely wont be displayed.

Comment: May I know how to present the created navigation controller?

Comment: you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130218/how-to-set-root-view-controller

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have set another view controller as root view controller in AppDelegate.

Comment: The code I have posted here is just a sample. I have many view controllers in my project. These 2 classes are just a part of my project. Any other way to present the created navigation controller?

Comment: If your DiffView have a navigation controller property, you can pass it to goToClassTwo() method and the method push Two() to it instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Okay.. I will try this one and let you know..

Comment: Thank you so much @zp_x.. It works..

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani you are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the updated code.

Code for class 'One':

```
import UIKit

class One {

    let btn = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 30, 30)
        btn.setTitle("Go", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: "goToClassTwo", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
    }

    func goToClassTwo(){
        if(AppGlobals().getIsFromDiffView()){
             //Using the navigation controller of DiffView
             AppGlobals().getController().pushViewController(Two(), animated: true)
        }else{
             self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Two(), animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

setter/getter class:

```
class AppGlobals: NSObject {

     var isFromDiffView = false
     var cntrlr: UINavigationController!

     func setIsFromDiffView(val: Bool){
         isFromDiffView = val
     }

     func getIsFromDiffView() -> Bool {
         return isFromDiffView
     }

     //Setting and getting DiffView Navigation controller
     func setController(cntrl: UINavigationController){
         cntrlr = cntrl
     }

     func getController() -> UINavigationController {
         return cntrlr
     }

}
```

DiffView class:

```
class DiffView {

    let btn = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 30, 30)
        btn.setTitle("Push", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
    }

    func btnAction(){
        AppGlobals().setIsFromDiffView(true)
        //Setting the navigation controller
        AppGlobals().setController(self.navigationController!)
        One().goToClassTwo()
    }
}
```

With this updated code, class 'Two' view controller is being displayed. 
Thank you @zp_x for your help.